# How can I visibly collapse a single row in a Silverlight 4 ListBox without actually removing the row?

Tags: c#, listbox, row, silverlight-4.0

Working in C# and Silverlight 4, I am using a ListBox bound to a data source. At this time three items are in the data source and thus appear in the ListBox. I need the third item not to appear in the ListBox but still to exist otherwise for various reasons.

Let's say my ListBox instance is called myListBox.

Essentially what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

myListBox.Rows[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Perhaps a more general question I should be asking is: "How can I access individual rows in the ListBox and change the properties of each?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide elements in the collection you are binding to, not the control itself.

Make use of [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and bind your ListBox to an observable collection in your viewmodel. It could be the observable collection of other viewodels if each item should support a lot of customizing. Then working with listbox becomes as easy as working with C# collections - you can perform any remove/add/hide logic without messing with control itself.

Edit:

Here's the idea of solution: you bind to `ElementsVM` field, not to `Elements` field. `Elements` field is used to set the model for this instance of VM class. Later, when you need to hide/show an element, use something like `_elementsVM[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`.

```
private ObservableCollection<Element> _elements;

public ObservableCollection Elements {
    get { return _elements; }
    set {
        _elements = value;
        var VMs = _elements.Select(el => new ElementVM(el, Visibility.Visible);
        _elementsVM = new ObservableCollection<ElementVM>(VMs);

        //NotifyPropertyChanged ("ElementVM")
    }
}

privae ObserableCollection<ElementVM> _elementsVM;

public ObservableCollection ElementsVM {
    get { return _elementsVM; }
}

public class ElementVM: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Element Element { get; set; }
    public Visibility IsVisible { get; set; }

    public ElementVM (Element element, Visibility visibility) {
        Element = element;
        IsVisible = visibility;
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here 
}
```

You'll have to work on my implementation of `ElementVM` a little: make sure that `PropertyChanged` is fired on setters and so on. You'll also need to bind `IsVisible` property of item template to the `IsVisible` property of `ElementVM`.

Comment: The ListBox is already bound to an ObservableCollection. (I am modifying old code, not developing new code.) Removing the element from the ObservableCollection using the Remove method causes problems for the app, and yet I don't see any way to simply hide/collapse the element either in the ListBox or in the ObservableCollection. Really no special customization is needed other than to cause one of the items to disappear on the screen but not behind the scenes.

Comment: @DaveInATL: I added to my answer, it's still a very raw solution, but you can get the idea

Comment: Dyppl: I decided to go in a different direction. I removed the item that I did not want to display from the item source and then worked around that in a couple of places in the code. It worked out well. I do want, however, to thank you for your time and insights. Dave